# basic regex c++ - forward slash and dot

Tags: c++, regex

I want to match forward slash `/` and dot `.` using c++ `regex_match`. I read that `\/` and `\.` works. But i get:

`warning: unknown escape sequence: '\/'`,

`warning: unknown escape sequence: '\.'`

and string doesnt match correctly too

I have tried to set ECMAScript flag for my regex, like this:

```
std::regex succes_r("^Sth\/Sth\.Sth).*", std::regex_constants::ECMAScript)
```

but nothing changed.

Comment: Use [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Comment: Note that ``\`` is a special character in c++, so you need to escape that as well.

Answer (score 1):

C++ dont handle unknown escapes like `\/` and `\.`.

and should be  `"^Sth/Sth\\.Sth).*"` which is parsed and handed to
regex engine as `^Sth/Sth\.Sth).*`

note that forward slash is *not* a regex special char.